# ¿Como hacer en javascript doble autocomplete?

Tags: javascript

He dejado el código que intento programar aquí: https://jsfiddle.net/9u7k312L/5/

Lo que quiero es que cuando escriba un término en el textbox, el select se complete con las opciones que contienen la palabra escrita en el textbox.

Por ejemplo.

Si escribo en el textbox **C**, el el select deben aparecer esas opciones:
**C - 1 y
C - 2**

Comment: te sugiero revisar la documentacion oficial: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Si, gracias, ya está arreglado el error del primero textbox pero sigo sin saber como sacar la segunda lista en el select.

Comment: revisa este post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740195/adding-options-to-a-select-using-jquery

Comment: Vale, sigo por aquí... jeje no consigo que cada vez que cambie el textbox, recoja el valor, compare y muestre en el select los items que contengan la palabra del textbox. (Código actualizado en el link del primer post)

Comment: Vuelvo a dejar el enlace del código: https://jsfiddle.net/9u7k312L/5/

Comment: @AntonioRuiz Revisando la documentación del JQueryUI y este componente, hay uno que calza en lo que quieres; usa el autocomplete en el combobox [ https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox ] y te evitas el trabajo de usar dos componentes, pues de no ser así, tendrás que programar un método que filtre la lista y este filtro lo tendrás que estar inicializando con el autocomplete en todo momento.